# Duplicate Soap Requests

Tags: web-services, weblogic11g

We are upgrading from `10.0` to `10.3.6`. Our web app is running in a DMZ and uses `.jar` files created with clientgen to invoke `JAX-RPC` web service operations deployed on our internal network by going through an XML firewall. My problem is that the XML firewall is behaving as though the HTTP request to invoke the web service operation was sent twice, when as near as I can tell it was only sent once. I set the following properties to view the soap traffic:

```
-Dweblogic.wsee.verbose=*
-Dweblogic.log.RedirectStdoutToServerLogEnabled=true
```

Unfortunately I don't have access to the XML firewall but I have been able to get the log entires for my service endpoints. I can see that it reports receiving duplicate requests but for the life of me I don't know how this can be happening. This does not happen when the web service clients are running on version `10.0`.

I've tried everything I can think of to troubleshoot this problem. I'm hoping somebody here can offer up some suggestions or perhaps tell me if this is a known issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [TCP Monitor](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/tcpmontutorial.html) to **intercept the SOAP traffic** between your server and the firewall.

This way you can tell if the requests are being sent twice or if there is some internal issue with the firewall.

Also, after you intercept the requests, you can use again TCP Monitor or [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/) to re-send the request to emulate the webserver and debug the firewall.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and for formatting my orignial post.  I'm actually going to spend my day today figuring out TCP monitoring using soupUI.  The duplicate request problem does not occur when I call the web service through soapUI.